# Android TCP read several line

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, bufferedreader

Does Android TCP Socket Client read one more line the response??

```
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); 
response = bufferedReader.readLine();
response = bufferedReader.readLine();
Log.i(TAG, "Response :: " + response);
```

I cannot read two line. Because my server will response
200 OK \n
Content.......

And the content will stream to the client every seconds, I don't wanna connect the socket every times. Can sbd help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example that will continue to read until an empty new line is found:

```
inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); 
String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); // add first line
while (line != "")
{
    response += line;
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
}
Log.i(TAG, "Response :: " + response);
```

Comment: ... until a *blank* line is found ... and what is happening here is that it is assembling the HTTP headers, which are terminated by a blank line. The response follows.

Comment: No. In his example he copied over the response with the next read line. I showed him how to continue reading until a delimiter is found. And we have no idea if it's HTTP or something else. Reading HTTP with sockets is making everything overly complex since a HTTP client exists in java for android

Comment: No. Downvoting. (1) You showed him how to keep reading until a blank line is found. Evidently you don't understand your own code. readLine() reads a line up to a newline, discards the newline, and returns the rest. If the rest is "" it was a blank line. That doesn't mean that the previous lines didn't have newlines too. Of course they did. That's what made them lines. (2) 200 OK appears in the first line of an HTTP response. (3) Your code doesn't do what you said it does and it doesn't answer the OP's question. (3) Reading HTTP with sockets is the OP's idea, not mine.

Comment: 1. Yes, I did. An empty line IS a delimiter since I stopped reading on it. Use the easiest method you can do achieve something. Using the ReadLine method was the easiest. 2. Yes? 3. It does ***excactly*** what I said. 3 (again). I did not state that it was your ID. I simply stated that it was a bad idea and there's no proof that it's HTTP that he is working with.

Comment: You described this as 'an example that will continue to read until a new line is found'. It isn't any such thing. It is an example that will read lines until an empty line is found. If you are now describing an empty line as a delimiter you should edit your reply accordingly. At present it doesn't do what it says on the tin. The discussion about HTTP belongs elsewhere as you now agree it has nothing to do with me.

Comment: Anyone can see that the example continues to read until a new empty line is found, even if you got very little programming experience. Read your first comment, you started to talk about HTTP, ***NOT me***. It's a bit funny that you say that all the comments is about me not adding the word "empty" to the answer description.

Comment: Now that you have finally corrected your description I would consider upvoting the downvote, if it answered the OP's question, which it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for you two response my question so details.
My Response would be sth like that

Protocol/1.0 200 OK(newline here)
Server: MyServer.com(newline here)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="big5"?><content>abc</content></xml>(newline here)

Comment: line = bufferedReader.readLine();
I think that my client is waiting in this line. So, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: while (line != ""), it should be while(!line.equals("")) by the way

Comment: And it is fine, I need to change the server response with one more new line to know the delimiter. Thanks you two~